# How to customize the first column of every row in html using css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to customize the first column of each row to have a background, but I am not able to find one solution for it.

This image will explain further:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKJ1j.jpg]

Answer (score 7):

Use the following code:

```
table tr td:first-child
{
    // Enter your CSS Here
}
```

if you provide us with some HTML, then may we can provide you with more specific answer. For now, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a colgroup to your table

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EbACd)

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>

etc...
```

Then

```
col:nth-child(1) {
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will give both first column at the header, and first column in each row the same width:

```css
table th:first-child, table tr td:first-child
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td:first-child {
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(82,82,210,1) 52%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>column 1</td>
   <td>column 2</td>
   <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The color can be changed to your preference - just go to a css generator - https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/